# Why is my UiProperty no longer editable in the GWT Designer?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-designer

For some reason I am no longer able to edit the UiField property in the GWT Designer.
The field acts like its read only.  When the field is selected the whole thing is highlighted instead of just the text. In fact all property fields do this, its just that UiField is the only one that doesn't have an edit window.

Recent changes to my environment have been an upgrade to Mountain Lion.

Environment:
Eclipse - Helios Rel 2
Mac OSX - Mountain Lion
Java 1.6.0

---

Update: 8/27/2012
I created a new GWT project and still can't edit properties in the designer.
I also installed Eclipse Juno, still the same.
On another machine, verified there is no problem on Lion.

So I can only assume now this is somehow related to Mountain Lion.

Anyone doing GWT development on Mountain Lion?

---

Update: 8/29/2012
This is apparently an identified problem with Eclipse and Mountain Lion.
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/911789/

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on ML using Juno, only workaround is to hand edit for now.